# How do I binary search a 2D array but keep the rows in the same place?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, binary-search

I have a 2D array that has 7 columns and I want to search it by the first column. The first column is a year, the second column is a month and then data for each of these. Here's an example.

```
2012 January  1 12 14 6  7
2012 February 7 8  19 2  8
2012 March    5 45 14 85 70
2012 April    8 23 17 89 67
```

So there are several years going from 1980 - 2015 with 12 months in each. I then want to search the 2D array by the year so it all stays in order. Almost like sorting a record. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Edit: This is a console application

Edit: Here is the 2D array in question;

```
namespace WeatherDatabaseBeta
{
    class Program
    {
    //creates string arrays using the text files shown
    public static string[] years = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/Year.txt");
    public static string[] months = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/Month.txt");
    public static string[] afs = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_AF.txt");
    public static string[] rains = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_Rain.txt");
    public static string[] suns = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_Sun.txt");
    public static string[] tmaxs = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_TMax.txt");
    public static string[] tmins = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_TMin.txt");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //changes console text to green
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        //runs Forge_Array
        Forge_Array();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Forge_Array()
    {
        //sets the number of rows in the 2D array to the length of the years array
        int arrayRows = years.Length;

        //sets the number of columns to 7
        int arrayColumns = 7;

        //creates new 2D string array. the size uses the values prior to this
        string[,] weather1 = new string [arrayRows, arrayColumns];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++)
        {
            //fills the 2D array using the values from the previous arrays
            //each array is used as a column in the 2D array
            weather1[i, 0] = years[i];
            weather1[i, 1] = months[i];
            weather1[i, 2] = afs[i];
            weather1[i, 3] = rains[i];
            weather1[i, 4] = suns[i];
            weather1[i, 5] = tmaxs[i];
            weather1[i, 6] = tmins[i];
        }

        //creates strings for the titles of all of the columns in the array
        string ytxt = "Year";
        string mtxt = "Month";
        string atxt = "Air Frost";
        string rtxt = "Rain";
        string stxt = "Sun";
        string matxt = "Max Temp";
        string mitxt = "Min Temp";

        //gets the lenght of the 2D array
        int rowLength = weather1.GetLength(0);

        //writes out the titles for the columns for the array
        Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
        Console.WriteLine("| {0 , -4} || {1, -10} || {2, -9} || {3, -6} || {4, -6} || {5, -6} || {6, -6} |", ytxt, mtxt, atxt, rtxt, stxt, matxt, mitxt);
        Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");

        //goes through the array and displays everything in the format shown below
        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("| {0, -4} || {1, -10} || {2, -9} || {3, -6} || {4, -6} || {5, -8} || {6, -8} |", weather1[i, 0], weather1[i, 1], weather1[i, 2], weather1[i, 3], weather1[i, 4], weather1[i, 5], weather1[i, 6]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean sort instead search?

Comment: No, it is already sorted by the year. I want to be able to enter a year, then display all 12 rows that have that year if that makes sense.

Comment: This question is unclear. You mention that you want it to "stay in order" but you also want to just search. Search shouldn't alter the ordering in any way, why do you think it would? Can you please explain your question better?

Comment: Could you add a little bit of code so we can inderstand in terms of C# how you defined your 2D array? This will likely allow people to give a quick answer..

Comment: Well say I input the year 1995. I then want it to show the rows that have 1995 in the first column and the data then in the rows that have 1995 in them at the start. So searching 1995 would just display the rows that have 1995 in the first column. EDIT: justb added code for the 2D array

Comment: Why not use Linq or even a generic collection? You'd have a lot more power at your finger-tips; I haven't seen the need for something like this since my DOS console C++ days.

Comment: If you could post an answer showing how to do that. It would be much appreciated

Comment: I also don't understand your requirement to "stay in order" if, as you explained in comments, all you want to display is the year 1995. That is, if your data is already ordered, filtering it shouldn't modify its ordering. Is this all you meant by your "stay in order" remark?

Comment: No, by stay in order I mean the row that is originally with any of the ones that have 1995 show with it. Basically ignore the stay in order remark, and I just need to know how to search and display all the rows that have 1995 in them

Answer (score 0):

If it is assignment about implementing binary searching this is not the answer.

In example you can see how to filter dataset very easily.

But if you want make your life easier working with such datasets I propose object oriented approach (I would do something with printing those banners but sorry no more time)(example compiles so you should be able to copy it run and play with it):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SOSorting
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static string[] years = { "1990", "1990", "1990", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1991", "1992", "1992" };// File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/Year.txt");

        public static string[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "January", "February", "March", "April", "January", "February" };// File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/Month.txt");

        public static string[] afs = { "5", "6", "7", "4", "2", "3", "7", "8", "1" }; //File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_AF.txt");

        public static string[] rains = { "50", "30", "40", "40", "25", "60", "30", "21", "21" };// File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_Rain.txt");

        public static string[] suns = { "85", "80", "81", "82", "80", "89", "90", "92", "75" };//File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_Sun.txt");

        public static string[] tmaxs = { "70", "60", "65", "65", "24", "24", "20", "75", "70" };//File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_TMax.txt");

        public static string[] tmins = { "10", "9", "8", "9", "10", "12", "12", "13", "21" }; //File.ReadAllLines(@"../../bin/Debug/WS1/WS1_TMin.txt");

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //changes console text to green
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            //runs Forge_Array
            Forge_Array();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void Forge_Array()
        {
            //sets the number of rows in the 2D array to the length of the years array
            int arrayRows = years.Length;

            //sets the number of columns to 7
            int arrayColumns = 7;

            //creates new 2D string array. the size uses the values prior to this
            string[,] weather1 = new string[arrayRows, arrayColumns];

            //create list of weather objects
            List<Weather> weatherList = new List<Weather>();

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++)
            {
                weatherList.Add(new Weather(years[i], months[i], afs[i], rains[i], suns[i], tmaxs[i], tmins[i]));
            }

            //creates strings for the titles of all of the columns in the array
            string ytxt = "Year";
            string mtxt = "Month";
            string atxt = "Air Frost";
            string rtxt = "Rain";
            string stxt = "Sun";
            string matxt = "Max Temp";
            string mitxt = "Min Temp";

            //gets the lenght of the 2D array
            int rowLength = weather1.GetLength(0);

            //writes out the titles for the columns for the array
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("| {0 , -4} || {1, -10} || {2, -9} || {3, -6} || {4, -6} || {5, -6} || {6, -6} |", ytxt, mtxt, atxt, rtxt, stxt, matxt, mitxt);
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Filtered to specific year");
            foreach (var weather in weatherList.Where(x => x.Date.Year == 1991)) // of course you can parametrize it
            {
                Console.WriteLine(weather);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("| {0 , -4} || {1, -10} || {2, -9} || {3, -6} || {4, -6} || {5, -6} || {6, -6} |", ytxt, mtxt, atxt, rtxt, stxt, matxt, mitxt);
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Not filtered");
            foreach (var weather in weatherList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(weather);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("| {0 , -4} || {1, -10} || {2, -9} || {3, -6} || {4, -6} || {5, -6} || {6, -6} |", ytxt, mtxt, atxt, rtxt, stxt, matxt, mitxt);
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Filtered by suns and year");
            foreach (var weather in weatherList.Where(x => x.Suns > 89 && x.Date.Year == 1991))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(weather);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("===============================================================================");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        private DateTime _date;
        private readonly string _year;
        private readonly string _month;
        private int _afs;
        private int _rains;
        private int _suns;
        private int _tmaxs;
        private int _tmins;

        public Weather(string year, string month, string afs, string rains, string suns, string tmaxs, string tmins)
        {
            if (tmins == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("tmins");
            if (tmaxs == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("tmaxs");
            if (suns == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("suns");
            if (rains == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("rains");
            if (afs == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("afs");
            if (month == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("month");
            if (year == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("year");

            //Have to use dictionary for quick translation
            int monthNumber = _months[month];

            //Date time will indicate first day of month but we care only about month and year anyway
            _date = new DateTime(int.Parse(year), monthNumber, 1);
            _year = year;
            _month = month;
            _afs = int.Parse(afs);
            _rains = int.Parse(rains);
            _suns = int.Parse(suns);
            _tmaxs = int.Parse(tmaxs);
            _tmins = int.Parse(tmins);
        }

        public DateTime Date { get { return _date; } }
        public int Afs { get { return _afs; } }
        public int Rains { get { return _rains; } }
        public int Suns { get { return _suns; } }
        public int Tmaxs { get { return _tmaxs; } }
        public int Tmins { get { return _tmins; } }

        private Dictionary<string, int> _months = new Dictionary<string, int>()
                {
                                { "January", 1},
                                { "February", 2},
                                { "March", 3},
                                { "April", 4},
                                { "May", 5},
                                { "June", 6},
                                { "July", 7},
                                { "August",8},
                                { "September", 9},
                                { "October", 10},
                                { "November", 11},
                                { "December", 12}
                };

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("| {0, -4} || {1, -10} || {2, -9} || {3, -6} || {4, -6} || {5, -8} || {6, -8} |", _year, _month, _afs, _rains, _suns, _tmaxs, _tmins);
        }
    }
}
```